# Grails not honoring JSONRenderer excludes for nested models?

Tags: json, grails

I've got a REST endpoint in my Grails application that's rendering out it's response to JSON. The `class` is being included in the JSON response as such:

```
{
    "class": "app.User"
    "id": null,
    "admin": false,
    "contact": {
        "class": "app.Contact",
        "id": "EEF448FE-ABDC-4C2E-B10B-CD448336FC51",
        "email": "qa_costco_drop_test@commercehub.com",
        "firstName": "first",
        "lastName": "last",
        "state": {
            "class": "app.State",
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I added several JSONRenderer beans to `grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy'

```
userJSONRenderer(JsonRenderer, User) {
    excludes = ['class']
}
contactJSONRenderer(JsonRenderer, Contact) {
    excludes = ['class']
}
stateJSONRenderer(JsonRenderer, State) {
    excludes = ['class']
}
```

And this got rid of the `class` attribute on the top-level User, but I'm still getting the Contact and State class:

```
{
    "id": null,
    "admin": false,
    "contact": {
        "class": "app.Contact",
        "id": "EEF448FE-ABDC-4C2E-B10B-CD448336FC51",
        "email": "qa_costco_drop_test@commercehub.com",
        "firstName": "first",
        "lastName": "last",
        "state": {
            "class": "app.State",
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any special configuration needed for nested models?

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to get the JSONRenderer to work for nested models.  I created a renderer for all my domain objects thinking Grails would sort it out for me, but no luck.  Interestingly enough, the renderers work at the top level for each type (i.e "/users", "/contacts", "/state"), just not for the nested objects.

I fixed this by registering custom object marshallers for each of the types in my object graph.  This works as expected, but is a bit painful.

The object marshaller is registered on the JSON class:

```
JSON.registerObjectMarshaller( User ) { User user ->
    return [
        id : user.id,
        admin: user.admin,
        contact: user.contact
    ]
}
```

You would need to add a marshaller for each of your domain classes to Bootstrap.groovy.

I actually went a bit further and followed [this example](http://compiledammit.com/2012/08/16/custom-json-marshalling-in-grails-done-right) using spring beans.  That article has some great comments discussing other ways to register the marshallers, including on the domain classes themselves.

If you go that route, be sure to read my comment about registering the marshallers in Bootstrap.groovy as it has changed since the article was written.